# Open child component in new tab and passing data between parent/child components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an angular project with two components ListComponent and DetailsModel, i want to edit  details model in a new tab, save it and refresh the list vue by my modifications. How can I do this? I tried it by redirection but i  can't refresh List vue after modification, is it possible using mat dialog? (open in it on new tab not a popup?)? Another way?

```
//app module
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '', component: ListComponent,
  pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
  path: 'details/:id',
  component: DetailsComponent
}

//List component
public detailsPath: string;
  ngOnInit(): void {  
    this.detailsPath = window.location.origin + '/details/';
}
// List HTML
<ng-container matColumnDef="Edit">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="action-link">
          <a href="{{detailsPath + element.id}}" target="_blank">Edit
          </a>
      </ng-container>

//Details Component
id: number;
myModel : MyModel;

constructor(private service: myService, private route: ActivatedRoute)

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id'];
this.service.getModelById(this.id).subscribe(m=>{
this.myModel = m;
}
}
}
save()
{
this.service.post(this.myModel).subscribe(m=>{
console.log('saved');
}
}
//Details HTML
   <button mat-raised-button color="accent"
                    class="mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-accent" (click)="save()">Save</button>
```

Comment: You can't communicate between tabs like that. If you want to act on events happening in another tab, you're going to have to open a socket connection with the server on each tab. The detail page would then send change notifications to the server, so the server can tell the listview to pull in a new update...

Comment: Thanks, so you are telling me that is impossible and i should use mat modal in popup mode?

Comment: It's not impossible, it just takes significant work.

Comment: Ok so i will check if there is a more simple solution